# Does zsh have any equivalent to BASH_ENV?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, debugging

I would like to be able to use something like [the BASH_ENV variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fENV) in `zsh`, however I can't find anything like it by Googling.

From `man bash`:

> `BASH_ENV`
>
> If this parameter is set when bash is executing a shell script, its value is
> interpreted as a filename containing commands to initialize the shell, as in
> `~/.bashrc`.  The value of `BASH_ENV` is subjected to parameter expansion,
> command substitution, and arithmetic expansion before being interpreted as a
> filename.  `PATH` is not used to search for the resultant filename.

Does `zsh` have something like this?

Comment: @rowboat Note that `BASH_ENV` in `bash` and `ENV` in `zsh` is not the same thing. `BASH_ENV` is only ever used for non-interactive shells, while `ENV` in `zsh` is different, and only used in `sh` or `ksh` emulation mode. This is similar to how `ENV` in `bash` works when that shell is in POSIX compatibility mode. See `man bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can think of is [`ZDOTDIR`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#index-ZDOTDIR_002c-use-of). Zsh reads its user initialization files in the directory `$ZDOTDIR`, falling back to `$HOME` if `ZDOTDIR` is unset. When zsh is running a script, it loads the user initialization file `.zshenv`.

So if in bash you'd have a file `/path/to/my-bash-env` containing

```
wibble
```

and you'd run `env BASH_ENV=/path/to/my-bash-env /path/to/script.bash`, then in zsh you can have a file `/path/to/my-zsh-dir/.zshenv` containing

```
if [[ -e ~/.zshenv ]]; then . ~/.zshenv; fi
wibble
```

and run `env ZDOTDIR=/path/to/my-zsh-dir /path/to/script.zsh`.