# How does the zsh which builtin work?

Tags: zsh, vim

My question is actually two-fold; I have a user defined function for TeX processing, called `texsed`, which is as following:

```
function texsed () {
    sed -i -f $S/tex_rule.sed $1 && pdflatex $2 $1
}
```

this definition is in the zshrc file `~/.zshrc`. Now, whenever I call `which texsed` from my zsh session, I get this output. The issue is that I cannot get the same output from vim, which I've tried to get by the following commands:

```
:r !which texsed
:r !zsh -c "which texsed"
```

neither of which worked.

I obviously do not understand the builtin command, so my question would (naively) be:

1. How does the zsh builtin `which` work?
2. How would I be able to get the definition of an alias or function defined through a config by such an external command?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A partial answer to my own question; sourcing the config and then executing the command seems to work: `:r !zsh -c "source $HOME/.zshrc; which texsed"`

Comment: Both of those are non-interactive invocations of zsh - I don't remember the rules for zsh, but it's possible it simply doesn't load your zshrc for non-interactive usage

Comment: Dingdingding: @muru is right, as `man zsh` confirms: *if the shell is interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc*; muru, would you post that as a quick answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `:!...` in Vim, it typically runs `$SHELL` with the arguments `-c` and `...`. This results in a non-interactive shell. Sand from [the zsh docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files):

> Commands are then read from `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`. If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from `/etc/zprofile` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`. Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from `/etc/zshrc` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`. Finally, if the shell is a login shell, `/etc/zlogin` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` are read.

So, with `:!...`, `.zshrc` is simply not read at all, and the function isn't defined.

---

As [I suggested in a related post on the Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7175/205), there're two ways to affect the invocation in `:!...` so that you can have this function defined:

1. Add an option to the shell being used to run `:!` commands using [`shellcmdflag`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shellcmdflag%27). From [`:h :!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21):

   ```
   On Unix the command normally runs in a non-interactive
   shell.  If you want an interactive shell to be used
   (to use aliases) set 'shellcmdflag' to "-ic".
   ```
2. Environment variables. Now, if this were bash, there's a quick solution: `$BASH_ENV`. But for zsh, there's no simple equivalent. See [Does zsh have any equivalent to BASH_ENV?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684597/70524) for a way by setting `ZDOTDIR`. But I'd still prefer this way as you can add exactly the configuration you need when using `:!` in Vim.